# ABP background job running multiple times under load balance

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

We have a service developed by ABP, and it has some background jobs, some background jobs are triggered by business action, and some background jobs are triggered by timer.

Now we deploy our service under load balance, then we go into a trouble. The scenario is, host service 1 is running, and at same time, there are background jobs are running in service 1, then we start up host service 2(before, it is stopped, for example maybe by maintain), since both service 1 and service 2 are use same database, so when startup service 2, it read uncompleted background jobs from database, and run it. But these jobs already processed by service 1, and it cause some unexpected result.

My question is, for my case, how to fix it and what is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

you need to write your background job as not to overlap the other instances. 
use a boolean flag like `IsItRunning`

1. set `IsItRunning=true`when your job starts.
2. start job if `IsItRunning == false`
3. set `IsItRunning=false` when your job finishes.

your all instances will start the job, but your real piece of code will only run once.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is a solution. And do you know if AbpBackgroudJob support LB by itself?